# definition of dllimport function not allowed

Tags: c, dllimport

While compiling a C code, I'm getting the following error:

```
c:\users\kbarman\documents\mser\vlfeat-0.9.13-try\mser\stringop.c(71): error C2491: 'vl_string_parse_protocol' : definition of dllimport function not allowed
```

In the file stringop.c, I have the following function:

```
VL_EXPORT char *
vl_string_parse_protocol (char const *string, int *protocol)
{
  char const * cpt ;
  int dummy ;

  /* handle the case prot = 0 */
  if (protocol == 0)
    protocol = &dummy ;

  /* look for :// */
  cpt = strstr(string, "://") ;

  if (cpt == 0) {
    *protocol = VL_PROT_NONE ;
    cpt = string ;
  }
  else {
    if (strncmp(string, "ascii", cpt - string) == 0) {
      *protocol = VL_PROT_ASCII ;
    }
    else if (strncmp(string, "bin",   cpt - string) == 0) {
      *protocol = VL_PROT_BINARY ;
    }
    else {
      *protocol = VL_PROT_UNKNOWN ;
    }
    cpt += 3 ;
  }
  return (char*) cpt ;
}
```

And VL_EXPORT is defined as follows:

```
#      define VL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
```

Can somebody please tell me what is causing this error and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Look up from that #define, there's a #ifdef that selects between dllexport and dllimport.  You need dllexport here so define that macro.

Answer (score 4):

As [documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62688esh.aspx), `dllimport` function are not allowed to have a body right there.

> [...] functions can be declared as dllimports **but not defined** as
>   dllimports.

```
// function definition
void __declspec(dllimport) funcB() {}   // C2491

// function declaration
void __declspec(dllimport) funcB();   // OK
```

Comment: If you declare a dllimport then you should not define it at all. It's an external.

Comment: Correct, thanks. The definition is not just separate, but also external.

Answer (score 2):

You are saying that the function is external, defined in a Dll. And then you are defining it in your code. This is illegal since is has to be one or the other, but not both external and internal.

My guess is that you simply need to change dllimport to dllexport. I assume that you are building this code into a library.

Comment: I'm not defining it in my main code actually. The main.c calls this function vl_string_parse_protocol, which is declared in a header file called stringop.h, and is defined in stringop.c.

Comment: it doesn't matter which translation unit defines it. If you declare it as external then you cannot define it.