# 'Mk4tcl_Init': definition of dllimport function not allowed

Tags: visual-studio, dll, tcl, dllimport, dllexport

I'm building a Tcl module **mk4tcl** (a .dll) [(part of metakit project)](https://github.com/jnorthrup/metakit/tree/master/tcl), I didn't find this module on the internet that is already built this is why I build it manually. However this module is already compiled in ActiveTcl, but in Tcl its not. I have to use it in Tcl because I'm building Tcl from source.

Building with `nmake` and i got the following errors:

```
..\src\mk4tcl.cpp(2597): error C2491: 'Mk4tcl_Init': definition of dllimport function not allowed
..\src\mk4tcl.cpp(2601): error C2491: 'Mk_Init': definition of dllimport function not allowed
..\src\mk4tcl.cpp(2605): error C2491: 'Mk4tcl_SafeInit': definition of dllimport function not allowed 
..\src\mk4tcl.cpp(2609): error C2491: 'Mk_SafeInit': definition of dllimport function not allowed
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
```

Im using `C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars32.bat`

It is and old project, it has dsp projects and vcprojects too, but the same error happens when building.
I installed Visual Studio 6 to build [mktcl.dsp](https://github.com/jnorthrup/metakit/tree/master/win/msvc60) project but again the same error happens.
I tried the following solutions
[definition of dllimport function not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657552/definition-of-dllimport-function-not-allowed)

This module uses [tcl.h](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/blob/main/generic/tcl.h) I have version **8.6.11**

[mk4tcl.cpp](https://github.com/jnorthrup/metakit/blob/master/tcl/mk4tcl.cpp) (parts)

```
#include "../tcldir/tcl.h"

EXTERN int Mk4tcl_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
  return Mktcl_Cmds(interp, false);
}

EXTERN int Mk_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
  return Mktcl_Cmds(interp, false);
}

EXTERN int Mk4tcl_SafeInit(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
  return Mktcl_Cmds(interp, true);
}

EXTERN int Mk_SafeInit(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
  return Mktcl_Cmds(interp, true);
}
```

[tcl.h](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/blob/main/generic/tcl.h) (parts of definition)

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef USE_TCL_STUBS
#define Tcl_InitStubs(interp, version, exact) \
    Tcl_PkgInitStubsCheck(interp, version, exact)
#endif


#if (defined(_WIN32) && (defined(_MSC_VER) || (defined(__BORLANDC__) && (__BORLANDC__ >= 0x0550)) || defined(__LCC__) || defined(__WATCOMC__) || (defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__declspec))))
#   define HAVE_DECLSPEC 1
#   ifdef STATIC_BUILD
#       define DLLIMPORT
#       define DLLEXPORT
#       ifdef _DLL
#           define CRTIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#       else
#           define CRTIMPORT
#       endif
#   else
#       define DLLIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#       define DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#       define CRTIMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#else
#   define DLLIMPORT
#   if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ > 3
#       define DLLEXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#   else
#       define DLLEXPORT
#   endif
#   define CRTIMPORT
#endif


#undef TCL_STORAGE_CLASS
#ifdef BUILD_tcl
#   define TCL_STORAGE_CLASS DLLEXPORT
#else
#   ifdef USE_TCL_STUBS
#      define TCL_STORAGE_CLASS
#   else
#      define TCL_STORAGE_CLASS DLLIMPORT
#   endif
#endif


#ifdef EXTERN
#   undef EXTERN
#endif /* EXTERN */

#ifdef __cplusplus
#   define EXTERN extern "C" TCL_STORAGE_CLASS
#else
#   define EXTERN extern TCL_STORAGE_CLASS
#endif


#define Tcl_Main(argc, argv, proc) Tcl_MainEx(argc, argv, proc, \
        ((Tcl_CreateInterp)()))
EXTERN void     Tcl_MainEx(int argc, char **argv,
                Tcl_AppInitProc *appInitProc, Tcl_Interp *interp);
EXTERN const char * Tcl_PkgInitStubsCheck(Tcl_Interp *interp,
                const char *version, int exact);
EXTERN void     Tcl_GetMemoryInfo(Tcl_DString *dsPtr)
```

Comment: The preprocessor symbol `BUILD_tcl` apparently isn't defined, which seems to toggle between creating the DLL with exported symbols, and consuming it.

Comment: You can reuse the ActiveTcl build of `mk4tcl`, couldn't you? Or, use a [tclkit builder](http://kitcreator.rkeene.org/kitcreator) including Metakit.

Comment: I didn't find it in the ActiveTcl install dir, just later I got it after searching in the lib folder under `C:\ActiveTcl8.5\lib\teapot\package\win32-ix86\lib\Mk4tcl2.4.9.7.1`, first I looked within the ActiveTcl `8.6` version's lib folder, in which seems it doesn't exist, only in AcitveTcl 8.5 lib dir.

Comment: Then, obtain a tclkit build from Kitcreator or use BAWT, this will give you a Tcl with Metakit included.

Comment: Something seems wrong here. Are you also building *Tcl*, or just your module?

Comment: I found the module already. It was in lib folder of ActiveTcl8.5. I was building Tcl too and this module.

Comment: *BUILD\_tcl* macro: **must be defined** when building *Tcl*, and **must NOT be defined** when building your module.

Comment: I think there are some patches that need to be applied before building the module. this tclkit builder does this: http://kitcreator.rkeene.org/kitcreator